# Softlayer API error "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using the java.net API to request the softlayer API.

```
String url = "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices.json";
String query = "objectFilter={\"invoices\":{\"createDate\":{\"operation\":\"betweenDate\",\"options\":[{\"name\":\"startDate\",\"value\":[\"04/01/2017 17:50:40\"]},{\"name\":\"endDate\",\"value\":[\"06/01/2017 17:50:40\"]}]}}}";
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
```

I get this error

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:891)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:690)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:661)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is due to characters sent in the request, characters like **[] {} : ""** , all of them must be encoded, to do that you can use method **URLEncoder.encode**.

```
URLEncoder.encode(filter,"UTF-8");
```

Below is the java code I used to solve the issue. This example is based on https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Define user credentials
        String username = "set me";
        String apikey = "set me";

        // Define Service url, method and header params
        String url = "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices.json";
        String filter = "{\"invoices\":{\"createDate\":{\"operation\":\"betweenDate\",\"options\":[{\"name\":\"startDate\",\"value\":[\"04/01/2017 17:50:40\"]},{\"name\":\"endDate\",\"value\":[\"06/01/2017 17:50:40\"]}]}}}";

        try {
           String encodedFilter = URLEncoder.encode(filter,"UTF-8");

           // Build the URL request
           URL urlRequest = new URL(url + "?objectFilter=" + encodedFilter);

            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlRequest.openConnection();

            // Encode user credentials to Base64 form
            String authString = username + ":" + apikey;
            String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes()));

            // Add authentication, request method and property
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                System.out.println("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer there are no more error however the result is wrong the objectFilter is not taken in charge by the softlayer server and i'm getting all the invoices!!

Comment: I updated my answer and the example, after investigation I noticed the problem was url encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetaly **Object Filters** are not yet implemented in the SoftLayer Java Api client, currently there's an open Issue regarding this, see:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/30

Meanwhile you may:

Use a Rest request as follows, to retrieve required information:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["04/01/2017 17:50:40"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["06/01/2017 17:50:40"]}]}}}
```

Retrieve getInvoices result and then filter it by using your own code; Or use any other SoftLayer API clients for supported programming languages, please see the following:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/